# game theory algorithms: how to proceed

Tags: algorithm, game-theory

Take an example: [Permutation Game](https://www.interviewstreet.com/challenges/dashboard/#problem/4eb167685f999)(interviewstreet.com). I would like to know how do I proceed in such questions.

P.S.: Please don't post the full algorithm(as that would spoil the fun), just a few pointers.

Comment: Can you please include the question here? It's not possible to view in my browser (and it may disappear in the future).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would setup a small game with a small N and a random permutation and then draw a complete **Alpha-Beta Tree**...

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha-beta_pruning

of all possible moves, and then work bottom-up making the optimal choice for each player at each point.

Then generalize from there once you see the pattern.

In game theory terminology you need to use **Backward Induction** to find the **Subgame Perfect Equilibrium**.

Comment: And how do you make the optimal choice? Alpha-beta does not deal with optimal choices, it deals with as-best-as-we-can-come-up-with guesses as to what the optimal choice is.

Comment: There is no guesswork if we lookahead at the __complete__ tree of all possible moves.  Draw a complete tree for an example game.  Start at the bottom, one level above the leaves there will be a game position whereby only one person chooses which piece to remove, write down the optimal choice at these first level branches.  Once they are all done move up to the second level branches.  Now you know what the outcome will be for the second level choices, (alpha beta), and so on until you reach the root.  You will then have a single sequence of optimal moves, and will see who will win the game.

Comment: Ah yes, that's what I had in mind too. Alpha-Beta tree just made me think of guesswork so we do not explore the entire tree. +1.

Answer (score 1):

`N` is rather small. In each turn, there are two possibilities for each number: remove that number or don't remove that number. Try both possibilities, resulting in an `O(N*2^N)` algorithm for each test case. In practice this will be lower since the game usually ends before all numbers are removed and you can cut the search short quite often.

So you want a backtracking function that tries all possibilities of removing the numbers and returns `1` if Alice wins and `2` if Bob wins. At depth `k` (first depth is `k = 0`), if `k % 2 = 0`, then it's Alice's turn. She wins if all the immediate recursive calls (that have depth `k + 1`) return `1`. If at least one of them returns `2`, then she loses, because there is at least one way for Bob to win.

Example run on `1 3 2`:

```
k = 0 - Alice removes 1:
    k = 1 - Bob removes 3 => Bob wins because only 2 remains
          - Bob removes 2 => Bob wins because only 3 remains (note: this step
            is not needed, as Bob already proved he can win at this k = 1)
      - Alice removes 3 => Alice wins because 1 2 is increasing
      - Alice removes 2 => Alice wins because 1 3 is increasing
```

So Alice definitely has a winning strategy (when both play optimally) if she removes `3` or `2` in the first move, because the recursive branches of these two never give Bob as the winner.

Example run on `5 3 2 1 4` (partial run):

```
k = 0 - Alice removes 5
    k = 1 - Bob removes 3
        k = 2 - Alice removes 2 => 1 4 => Alice wins
    k = 1 - Bob removes 2
        k = 2 - Alice removes 3 => 1 4 => Alice wins
    k = 1 - Bob removes 1
        k = 2 - Alice removes 3 => 2 4 => Alice wins
    k = 1 - Bob removes 4
        k = 2 - Alice removes 3
            k = 3 - Whatever Bob removes, he wins
        k = 2 - Alice removes 2
            k = 3 - Whatever Bob removes, he wins
        k = 2 - Alice removes 1
            k = 3 - Whatever Bob removes, he wins
  ...
```

As you can see, there is at least one way for `Bob` to end up winning if `Alice` starts by removing `5`. If you do the same for her other possibilities, you will probably get the same result. Thus, it's `Bob` who will definitely win if he plays optimally.

Answer (score 0):

**Pen and Paper**

Use pen and paper, make sure you understand the rules of the game exactly, then think of all possible strategies for the game.

For a relatively simple problem like this, think backwards from the point when game is won, unrolling one step at a time and making sure the player who made that step could not have made a better step, that's the optimality requirement.

For more complicated problems, read up Wikipedia on game theory.